# How do I establish an HTTPS connection from client by the server public key to that specific server?

Tags: c#, https, openssl, private-key, public-key

I have a client-server model.

The server generated a key pair and shipped public keys to all the clients.
In order to confirm the server is the real server I gonna to make connection to, I want to establish an HTTPS connection by the server public key to that specific server.

How can I do that? Or is there any better way to authenticate the server?

This is the first time I ask at stackoverflow. So, if you have any suggestion please don't hesitate to tell me. Thank you.

PS: Source code is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I need is the term "Certificate and Public Key Pinning".

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning